Need to replace multiple values in a text string, within the given column in one query/step
Problem statement:
I would like to replace multiple values within a text string only if found, all in one step.
Example: In my column of 8000 rows,
I want to replace @ symbol with *40 in text string like first.lastname@email.org
I want to replace "Org" to "Com"
I want to replace CP-ZI with CP-PREF-ZI only if the text begins with CP-ZI
I want to replace CP-ZE with CP-PREF-ZE only if the text begins with CP-ZE
I want to replace CP-ZL with CP-PREF-ZL only if the text begins with CP-ZL
More detailing: I have multiple values like this, that needs to be replaced for a given column. I want to be able to do all the replaces with one query, instead of creating multiple replace queries.
I do not want to replace the entire cell content. Only a partial text string, like shared in the above example.
Please help me build a M query that will solve this.
My column looks something like this:
enter image description here
I tried the below M query:
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Remark Replace @ to *40",each [Remark], each if [Remark] = "CP-ZI" then "CP-PREF-ZI" else if [Remark] = "CP-ZE" then "CP-PREF-ZE" else if [Remark] = "CP-ZL" then "CP-PREF-ZL" else if [Remark] = "CP-SX" then "CP-PREF-SX" else if [Remark] = "CP-ET" then "CP-PREF-ET" else if [Remark] = "CP-ZD" then "CP-PREF-ZD" else if [Remark] = "CP-EP" then "CP-PREF-EP" else if [Remark] = "CP-AL" then "CP-PREF-AL" else if [Remark] = "CP-IL" then "CP-PREF-IL" else [Remark], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Remark"})

Then I tried text.Contains, however that does not replace anything :(
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Remark Replace CP-ZI to CP-PREF-ZI",each [Remark], each if Text.Contains([Remark], "¤") then "*40" else if Text.Contains([Remark], "@") then "*40" else [Remark], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Remark"})


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    TransformedTable = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"My column", each 
        let
            textWithSymbolReplaced = Text.Replace(_, "@", "*40"),
            textWithOrgReplaced = Text.Replace(textWithSymbolReplaced, "Org", "Com"),
            textWithCPZIReplaced = if Text.StartsWith(textWithOrgReplaced, "CP-ZI") then Text.Replace(textWithOrgReplaced, "CP-ZI", "CP-PREF-ZI") else textWithOrgReplaced,
            textWithCPZEReplaced = if Text.StartsWith(textWithCPZIReplaced, "CP-ZE") then Text.Replace(textWithCPZIReplaced, "CP-ZE", "CP-PREF-ZE") else textWithCPZIReplaced,
            textWithCPZLReplaced = if Text.StartsWith(textWithCPZEReplaced, "CP-ZL") then Text.Replace(textWithCPZEReplaced, "CP-ZL", "CP-PREF-ZL") else textWithCPZEReplaced
        in
            textWithCPZLReplaced
    }})
in
    TransformedTable


The following assumes

There is only a single instance of @xxx.org in each line

If there might be more than one, it is a simple change, but would take a bit longer to run


The @xxx.org does not necessarily need to be preceded by xxxx.xxxx as you show, but if that is the case, again, only a minor tweak would be needed.

(This was the least complicated method I could think of to do your replacements with regard to @xxxx.org => *40xxxx.com, although if you want to replace ALL of the @ with *40 it might not be necessary)

First, add a custom function by pasting the code below into a blank query
Rename this fnRegexReplace

//Rename Query:  fnRegexReplace

(text as nullable text,pattern as nullable text,replace as nullable text, optional flags as nullable text) =>
    let
        f=if flags = null or flags ="" then "" else flags,
        l1 = List.Transform({text, pattern, replace}, each Text.Replace(_, "\", "\")),
        l2 = List.Transform(l1, each Text.Replace(_, "'", "\'")),
        t = Text.Format("<script>var txt='#{0}';document.write(txt.replace(new RegExp('#{1}','#{3}'),'#{2}'));</script>", List.Combine({l2,{f}})),
        r=Web.Page(t)[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children],
        Output=if List.Count(r)>1 then r{1}[Text]{0} else ""
    in Output

Then use this code:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Remarks", type text}}),
    Replacements = List.Accumulate(
        List.Zip({{"CP-ZI","CP-ZE","CP-ZL"},{"CP-PREF-ZI","CP-PREF-ZE","CP-PREF-CL"}}),
        Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",
            {"Remarks", each fnRegexReplace(_,"@([^@]*)(\\.)(org)","*40$1.com","i")}),
        (s,c)=>Table.TransformColumns(
                s,
                {"Remarks", each if Text.StartsWith(_,c{0})
                             then Text.Replace(_,c{0},c{1}) 
                             else _ , type text}))
in
    Replacements

Because of the use of Regular Expressions, this may take a while to run. If the time is excessive, a different algorithm might be faster. Let me know.

